# i want to setup ultra wide angle camera and normal camera for android device

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-vision-camera

I am using it to make the camera recording ultra-wide angle and normal,
for that, I use min zoom as an ultra-wide angle and neutral zoom as a normal camera.
it works fine for IOS devices but I try on Android if the device has multiple cameras then still it gives me only one camera device.

VisionCamera Version
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.16.2",

```
const devices = useCameraDevices();
const deviceAndroid = switchCameraToFront ? devices?.front : devices.back;
const isWideAngleCamera = deviceAndroid?.devices.includes('ultra-wide-angle-camera');
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)